# KH 0300 or Reason

Tags: monitors, monitor-calibration

I own some studio speakers (Klein and Hummel 0300, purchased in January 2012), and they have really tested my wits.  Not because I regret my purchase, but I stil have several problems with them.

At the beginning, when I receive them at my house, I opened them to find a mid driver pulled down. This probably happen during transportation. I sent them back to Sennheizer for a fix. Their answer to the problem was:

-Mid driver remplacement.

After the repair, I found several other problems with the monitors.  For example, the two speakers were not matching output levels.  One was playing less loud than than another.

Another question; when using Propellerhead's Reason, the kicks and bass is drowned out -  damaged or like when the audio is clipping. I can't understand if this happens becuase of the speakers, sound card or (source) Reason?

Which one is faulty? The speakers are still under warranty.

My Gear:

```
Sound Card:Motu 828 Krk
Computer:Mac OS Leopard
Software:Reason 5.0
Monitors:KH 030
```

Answer (score 1):

If your level meters are in red or there's a "clip warning" light on, then the audio is clipping or has been clipped. When digital clipping occurs it works like an absolute or ideal limiter, everything going over is limited to the maximum amplitude level and it distorts the entire signal during the clipping (basically it transforms the signal during the clipping to include some properties of a square wave, which sounds harsh) as well as limits the amplitude (the sound "pumps").

Software is absolute, so if there are no warnings (e.g. clip warning or red light over a level meter) or errors, then it doesn't do anything that you (or the default settings) haven't told it to do.

The proper functioning of speakers can only be determined by technicians or the manufacturer.